# Can't capture swipe right in ionic because of side menu

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

In my view I have:

```html
<ion-content on-swipe-left="onSwipeLeft()" on-swipe-right="onSwipeRight()">
```

Swiping left works fine and calls onSwipeLeft(). But if I swipe right it slides open the side menu rather than calling onSwipeRight(). Is there any way to make sure onSwipeRight() gets called rather than the side menu being opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the [ion-side-menu-content](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSideMenuContent/) directive and set `drag-content: false`.